# Running VMWare Workstation 14 on a VM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-workstation, packer

I have set up VMWare Workstation on a esxi 6.0 hosted VM. (Ubuntu 16.04.05)

I am trying to run some `packer` builds that use the specific (VMWare Workstation) hypervisor.

The builds get stuck  randomly;

The only thing I notice in my logs is:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/vmware/hostd-1.log 
2018-09-12T19:10:43.227+03:00 info hostd[31791] [Originator@6876 sub=Libs] SOCKET creating new socket, connecting to /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket
2018-09-12T19:10:43.227+03:00 info hostd[31791] [Originator@6876 sub=Libs] SOCKET connect failed, error 2: No such file or directory
2018-09-12T19:12:43.228+03:00 info hostd[31791] [Originator@6876 sub=Libs] SOCKET creating new socket, connecting to /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket
```

What is more ...

```
$ sudo systemctl status vmware-USBArbitrator.service
● vmware-USBArbitrator.service - LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-09-12 19:27:02 EEST; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10639 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 12 19:27:01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator....
Sep 12 19:27:02 vmware-USBArbitrator[10639]: [11B blob data]
Sep 12 19:27:02 systemd[1]: vmware-USBArbitrator.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 12 19:27:02 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator..
Sep 12 19:27:02 systemd[1]: vmware-USBArbitrator.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 12 19:27:02 systemd[1]: vmware-USBArbitrator.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Could it be that it is not possible (or at least some requirements should be met) to build a vm image on a VM guest?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few prerequisites to run a nested virtual guest.

- You need to confirm that your physical host processor supports Intel
  VT-x and EPT or AMD-V and RVI.
- Your guest machine needs to be on Hardware version 9 or later.
- Enable Virtualized HV on your guest machine.

You can enable virtualized HV on the guest machine by:

1. Login to vCenter (this setting is not available in the C#/desktop client)
2. Power down the guest machine
3. Edit the settings of the guest machine
4. Check the box next to "Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to the guest operating system"
5. Click OK to save the changes

Source:
[Running Nested VMs](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970)